# How to restart Jenkins Pipeline build with the previous inputs ( data )

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins on my machine and i am using jenkins pipeline and Blue ocean.

I have a job, It is about multi stage and each stage has inputs.

When run a job,User should enter a a lot of information.

When a build fails, user should rebuild the job and re enter the information again.

My question here : How to restart Jenkins Pipeline build with the previous ( without entering the information again ) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the classic view. Once in classic view, go to the run  of the job you would like to repeat, and on the left sidebar there's a replay option. that will use your previously set parameters

Comment: I tried to use Replay : It wants from me to write script. I do not know it is right or not

Comment: it doesn't require new code, it just uses what ran last time. so just click replay and start/build